# Scope Issue. How to reference method?

Tags: java

I have this scenario:

```
public class A
{
  private final Integer index;

  public Integer getIndex() { return index; }

  public static class B
  {
    //unimportant
  }
}

public class C extends B
{
  //how to reference getIndex() here?
}
```

How can I call getIndex() in class C's body?

Answer (score 3):

Odd scenario... but you'd have to move class C to also be an inner class inside class A. Shrug? Curious why are you extending an inner class in the first place? What are the restrictions of the design that are causing this? Not judging you at all. Having the thinking behind the design could aide in possibly finding an alternative solution.

```
public class A
{
   // make sure final value is set here or in constructor
   private final Integer index = 0;

   public Integer getIndex() { return index; }

   public static class B
   {
      //unimportant
   }

   //Doesn't make much sense... but...
   public class C extends B
   {

      //can now call getIndex()
      public void callGetIndex() {
         getIndex();
      }

    }
}
```

*Bonus research:*
For those that are maybe as curious as me and thought about using this to reference the function from another file. If you compile C in another file, and try accessing getIndex by using the enclosing **this**:

```
A.this.getIndex();
```

Sadly that won't work because even though C extends B, it still needs to be enclosed by A for that methodology to work. You get this compile time error:

```
C.java:5: error: not an enclosing class: A
        A.this.getIndex();
         ^
1 error
```

**Hey cool! another answer, based off @mzl's answer below:**
So interestingly enough, You can keep B static and extend both classes to get what you want to do. This is useful for example if you can not edit file A.java, because A.java is 3rd party functionality. *(give @mzl credit here for his answer below)*

Here is how you'd do it that way! ( Tested this compiles via javac A.java C.java )

**A.java**

```
public class A
{
  private final Integer index = 0;

  public Integer getIndex() { return index; }

  public static class B
  {
    //unimportant
  }

}
```

C.java

```
public class C extends A
{

    public class D extends A.B {
        //can now call getIndex()
         public void callGetIndex() {
            getIndex();
         }

    }

 }
```

I've created a static over flow project proving @mzl's theory here:
https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverflow_Q_39441077

One gothcha. You'll notice I create an instance of C before D to make sure there is access to getIndex(). I haven't tested what happens if you instantiate D directly I will do that later and post the results.

---

Late update on that instantiate D directly test.

I added `C.D testD = new C.D();` in my static main function:

```
$ sh build.sh
StackOverflowQuestion39441077.java:5: error: an enclosing instance that contains C.D is required
        C.D testD = new C.D();
                    ^
1 error
```

The compiler helps us by not letting us do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend (non-statically) a inner class you must extend the outer class aswell.

You could do it this way:

```
public class A
{
    private final Integer index;

    public Integer getIndex() { return index; }

    public static class B {}
}

public class D extends A{

    public class C extends B{}
}
```

Comment: So curiously enough B can stay static and we can use your method here to getting a compiling working solution. This is good because if maybe he is extending B because he can't change the implementation of the file A then this would allow him to do what he wants.  Because class C is not static if can access getIndex inside class D when A's B is static. Just because class B is static does not make it's extending classes have to be static too.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks! I edited my answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `C` extends `B` which does not have a `getIndex()` method. `C` must extend `A` to inherit that method.

Answer (score 0):

(I feel it is an interesting theoretical question but with little meaning in practice.)

You can't event access `A.getIndex` from `B` because `B` is static, and `getIndex` is not, so to invoke `getIndex` you need a non-null instance of `A`.

Assuming you could make `B` non-static, you couldn't either, because your scheme becomes contradictory:

- In one hand, class `B` is inner, so to instantiate a new object a previous non-null instance of `A` is required:

```
    A a=new A();
    B b=a.new B();
```

- But in the other hand, class `C` is a top-level (not inner) class, so it may be directly instantiated. However, being a subclass of `B`, it is subject to the same restrictions as its superclass: It needs an instance of `A`. Contradictory!

The only way I think to make it work is to declare `getIndex` **static**, so no instance of `A` would be needed (in fact, neither subclassing from `B` would be a problem).